# Email composer into UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have this container view that opens, and inside it, i want to add the email composer, when i have some title and more stuff in this `UIView` window.

But it seems that i can't add the composer , but only to view controller .

Is there a way to add it into my UIView ? i couldn't find that implementation on the net .

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailController setSubject:@"Feedback"];
    NSString *emailBody = @"me";
    [mailController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
  [view presentModalViewController:mailController.view animated:YES]; //add to view
```

Comment: Try with adding as subview. `[view addSubView:mailController.view];`

Comment: You can't. If you wanted it to appear over the view, you can use Delegate protocols to send a message back to your root View Controller to present it. This should slide in over your UIView... I guess it depends on how you've setup your hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, actually MFMailComposeViewController is a `UIViewController` subclass and you can only add it inside an `UIViewController` not an `UIView`.

Adding an UIViewController inside an UIView couldn't respect the MVC design pattern. The purpose of a `view` is only to show data sent by the `controller` and call controller's actions when the user is making an action on the `view`

Comment: thanks, so you can't design the ui of a composer ? seems very old that Apple decides for you how the ui of this view will look . i want to create some view with my own UI design.